# Difference between <(commands) and >(commands) in process substitution

Tags: linux, bash, process-substitution

In [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) I can see two syntaxes:

```
>(command_list)
```

and

```
<(command_list)
```

Often I use the second syntax. But I have no idea what is exactly the difference between the two? searching about that yields nothing special.

Comment: To whom downvoted, please drop a comment to explain what's wrong with my question.

Comment: I didn't vote on your question, but one thing that stands out is that Bash's manual (`man 1 bash` or, more specifically, `info bash "process substitution"`) explains the meaning of the two forms. Sure, knowing about the documentation and how to search through it is not trivial, but some users probably expect it from question askers.

Comment: @fra-san: Thanks for pointing that. As you can see I have added the link to the documentation, but it didn't mention the difference between the two.

Comment: The link you added is not the documentation, that's some guide written by some guy on the internet. The documentation, as displayed by `info bash "process substitution"` can be found online as well on the [GNU official website](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: `info bash "process substitution"` returns nothing. I am a very new to Linux/Unix in general. I've tried several times to read docs but unfortunately, not all of them are clear, even worse making things very vague. I don't need to be a science computer student to understand that, I am a lambda user if that helps.

Comment: If on Debian or derivative, you may need to install a `bash-doc` package.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thank you, now it works!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use:

```
consumer <(feeder)
```

For the *output* of `feeder` to be fed to `consumer`, when `consumer` cannot take its input from stdin (in which case you'd simply use `feeder | cousumer`) but only from file names given as argument.

In that case, `feeder`'s output is the writing end of a pipe, and the expansion of `<(feeder)` is a filename (usually `/dev/fd/<x>`, though could be a named pipe on systems that don't support `/dev/fd/<n>`) which once open (by `consumer`) gets you to the *reading* end of that pipe.

Symmetrically, you use:

```
feeder >(consumer)
```

For those `feeder` commands that don't send their output to stdout (where you could just do `feeder | consumer` again), but to a file whose name you need to pass as argument.

Then `consumer`'s *input* is the reading end of a pipe, and `>(consumer)` expands to a filename which once opened (by `feeder`) gets you to the writing end of that pipe.

It's more common to use `<(...)` because it's useful in commands that take more than one input like:

```
diff -u <(cmd1) <(cmd2)
```

While it's less common for commands to produce more than one output, or for commands not to be able to send their output to stdout. A common exception is:

```
feeder | tee >(consumer1) >(consumer2) | consumer3
```

Where `tee` is a typical command that sends some output to more than one file (in addition to stdout) in parallel.

You may have seen things like:

```
tar cf - somedir |
 gzip -9 |
 tee >(shasum > dir.tgz.shasum) >(md5sum > dir.tgz.md5sum) > dir.tgz
```

To send the output of `gzip` (here a compressed tar archive) to the output file as well as `shasum` and `md5sum` to generate and store the checksums at the same time.